# Program prevents mouse movement

Tags: python, winapi, python-3.x

I have a click bot for a game and haven't used it for a while.
I installed it new(maybe there was a new version) and my bot isn't working anymore. It seems like the event is somehow blocked when the game is activated.

I activate the game, with this:

```
shell=win32com.client.Dispatch("Wscript.Shell")
success = shell.AppActivate("Game)
```

I tried 2 methods to move the mouse:

```
win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
```

That gives me this error.

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

The other method is:

```
nx = int(x*65535/win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0))
ny = int(y*65535/win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE|win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE,nx,ny)
```

which doesn't work and doesn't give me an error message.

When the game window is not activated, the cursor moves without a problem.

Does anybody know a workaround for this?

Edit: I am using Microsoft Windows 8.1

Comment: Perhaps the game uses DirectX? SetCursorPos wouldn't work then, you could try `SendInput` instead.

Comment: SO, the game might have switched to using DirectX with an update?
I will look further into it, when I am at home.
Do you know a python-package, that provides this SendInput-functionality? A quick google-search makes it seem a bit complicated to use SendInput.

Comment: Can you give an example, @Phillip ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried out ctypes and that works:

```
ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Not to grave dig old threads, but I ran into this. Try running your script as admin so if your running in CMD make sure you open it as administrator.  It worked for me, very simple.  I was using python, and windows 10.

Comment: Would you have some more information? Like the Python version you are using, and why you need to be an admin to run a standard user program (perhaps some system-wide configuration tip) ? Cheers-