# How does programs that supress key-presses in python work?

Tags: python, click, anti-cheat

I am trying to automate a process in a program but I ran into a little problem. With this code:

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

sleep(2)
pyautogui.click(1500, 1300)
```

I get an error saying

```
pywintypes.error: (0, 'SetCursorPos', 'No error message is available')
```

How does computer programs know where the input is comming from? Why does this key-pressing technique work on so many places but in some applications it, because they've implemented some "anti pseudo-click" fix, doesn't work?

I've already solved my problem, I want to know HOW a company might prevent mouse click programs! I don't want to know how to enter mouse clicks into a program, I've already figured that out :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program prevents mouse movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197544/program-prevents-mouse-movement)

Comment: I am looking for ways a program might PREVENT mouse clicks, not how I am supposed to solve my problem. I want to integrate some of those techniques into my own programs. Again, I am NOT trying to stimulate mouse click, like the post "Program prevents mouse movement".